# composition/power of relation

Tags: relations

Let $A$ be a finite set so: $|A|=j$ and $S$ a relation on $A$.

Prove that there are $i,j\in \mathbb{N}$ that $i>j$ and $S^{i}=S^{j}$.

I tried to prove it with the definition, but without any success.

Comment: Didn't $A$ happen to be *finite*?

Answer (score 2):

This does not have to be true if $\mathbb N$ is allowed to be unfinite.

If e.g. $A=\mathbb N$ and $nSm\iff m=n+1$ then $nS^im\iff m=n+i$ and $i\neq j\implies S^i\neq S^j$.

---

**edit** (after edit of question).
If $A$ is finite then the number of relations on $A$ is finite so the function on $\mathbb N$ to the set of relations on $A$ prescribed by $i\mapsto S^i$ cannot be injective. This means that $i,j\in\mathbb N$ must exist with $i>j$ and $S^i=S^j$.

Comment: Why the function cannot be injective?

Comment: If $X$ is infinite and $Y$ is finite then a function $f:X\to Y$ cannot be injective. Do you understand?

Comment: I can't find a proof for this theorem. I only found that if $X$ and $Y$ are finite sets and if there is an injective function so $|X|=|Y|$

Comment: Can you prove yourself that e.g. a function  $f:\mathbb N\to\{0,1,2\}$ is not injective? This purely on base of the definition of injectivity.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose not, then for all $i$ and $j$, $S^i\neq S^j$. But now $S^i\subseteq A\times A$ for all $i$, and how many subsets can $A\times A$ even have?

Comment: I think that it has $2^{n^{2}}$ but how does it help us in solving the problem?

Comment: How many natural numbers are there? Surely more than that.